# How can I check the local image is up to date with registry image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to find out the latest timestamp for an image in a private Docker registry using the v2 API without first pulling the image to my local and compare it into local image created date.

***Is that possible with script or curl with awk ?***

Answer (score 1):

You can **execute the pull command** to make sure your local docker repo is up-to-date.
If you try pull the image, docker will compare the remote image digest with local image digest. If the digests are equal, docker won't update the image and will say it is up-to-date.

**Example below:**

```
    docker pull myrepo/app:v0.1
    car0.1: Pulling from myrepo
    Digest: sha256:cb7b50c26124ffba06fd559fa86751e5fe9b4a49990fc8dbf4dfaf0fb9d58206
    Status: Image is up to date for myrepo/app:v0.1
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the OP specifically asked "without first pulling the image to my local" and this solution pulls the image to the local machine.

Seems to me the simple solution would be to add something like `--dry-run` as an option to the pull command and perhaps `-q` for quiet (just set the exit status) but that doesn't seem to exist.